# How to simplify the following class

Tags: java, simplify

Hi i'm new to programming and I i'm wondering how I can simplify the following code. Is there a way i can set a variable that will change instead of setting month 1-6?

```
double RATE;
double SAVING; 
double MONTH1;
double MONTH2;
double MONTH3;
double MONTH4;
double MONTH5;
double MONTH6;

System.out.print("Enter the monthly saving amount: ");
SAVING = input.nextDouble();

RATE = 1.00417;

MONTH1 = SAVING * RATE;
MONTH2 = (MONTH1 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH3 = (MONTH2 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH4 = (MONTH3 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH5 = (MONTH4 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH6 = (MONTH5 + SAVING) * RATE;

System.out.println("After the sixth month, the account value is $" + (float) MONTH6);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Guys, please don't rate questions down due to 1) Lack of knowledge/experience, or 2) Lack of prior research.

S.O. is a resource for many programmers of all skill levels to learn, let's not discourage new users by rating down their questions unless it's apparent there was no effort put in to solve the problem.

Comment: @EvanBechtol I didn't downvote, but the tooltip on the downvote button explains when downvoting is appropriate: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". So, the lack of prior research **is** a good reason to downvote. And quite frankly, this question is border-line.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't say that you did dowvote! I just noticed someone had down-voted and thought it was slightly unnecessary.
OP asked a legitimate question. Could he/she have done more research? Absolutely. But we have to remember that S.O. often appears as a top search, so it's important to keep this in our minds as new users ask questions. 

I simply think that instead of down-voting a user on their VERY FIRST POST, perhaps we could be better hosts and direct them on our practices here and what we expect of users and their questions.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here:

```
MONTH1 = SAVING * RATE;
MONTH2 = (MONTH1 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH3 = (MONTH2 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH4 = (MONTH3 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH5 = (MONTH4 + SAVING) * RATE;
MONTH6 = (MONTH5 + SAVING) * RATE;
```

is you've written the essentially same thing over and over again.

For repetitive tasks like that, a **loop** is always a better solution.

With a loop, you don't even need all those `MONTH` variables. Here's an example of calculating the account value after `totalMonths` months using a loop to eliminate repetitive code:

```
int accountValue = 0;
int monthNumber = 0;

while (monthNumber < totalMonths) {                // Do what's inside the brackets as long as monthNumber is less than totalMonths.
    accountValue = (accountValue + saving) * rate; // Update the account value with saving and rate.
    monthNumber = monthNumber + 1;                 // Increase monthNumber by one.
}

System.out.println("After " + totalMonths + " months, the account value is $" + accountValue);
```

At the end of the above code `accountValue` will have the total account value after `totalMonths` months have passed.

This is a very simple example. Experiment with it and make sure you understand it 100%.

<sub>Note that I wrote my variable names in lowercase ([camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), to be exact), as it's the common [naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) in Java.</sub>

Comment: You meant camelCase in your note.

Comment: It should also be noted that variables declared in ALL CAPITALS are largely considered to be constants; they are never changed during runtime of the program. +1 on response @zenith